# mgo convert mapreduce to aggregations command

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mgo

I am trying to convert this function here from mapreduce to aggregation.

https://github.com/mendersoftware/deviceauth/blob/be2f9745e14bbe87121d99ac6c396f41ca7438e2/store/mongo/datastore_mongo.go#L826

The result from above function will be `[{pending 1}]`.

When I run my match group I get `[{pending 0}]` from the following code below:

```
    mat := bson.M{
            "$match": bson.M{"device_id": devId},
    }

    grp := bson.M{
            "$group": bson.M{
                    "_id": "$status",
                    "count": bson.M{
                            "$sum": 1,
                    },
            },
    }

    pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{mat,grp})
    pipe.One(&result)
```

But the same I think command in mongo shell gives `[{pending 1}]`.

```
db.getCollection("auth_sets").aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        device_id:"5c79601d152ece00012f5831"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id:"$status",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
     }
},
]);
```

How can I get it so my pipe will return `[{pending 1}]`?

I am changing it so I can use Mongo Atlas with does not allow mapreduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mgo` query structure is OK, the problem is the name of the `count` field. The model expects `Value`:

```
var result []struct {
    Status string `bson:"_id"`
    Value  int
}
```

So change the `$group` stage to this:

```
grp := bson.M{
        "$group": bson.M{
                "_id": "$status",
                "value": bson.M{   // Note lowercased "value"!
                        "$sum": 1,
                },
        },
}
```

And it should work. Or change the model if you can:

```
var result []struct {
    Status string `bson:"_id"`
    Value  int    `bson:"count"`
}
```

Only one of them needs to be changed, to be aligned with the other.

One last thing: If you use `Query.One()`, then the `result` must not be a slice (`One()` expects one document exactly).

Use a slice type for `result` if you use e.g. `Query.All()`.

So if you're going to use `Query.One()`, use result:

```
var result struct {
    Status string `bson:"_id"`
    Value  int    `bson:"count"`
}
```

Also `Query.One()` and `Query.All()` return an error, do check it!

Comment: I tried both ways and it still shows pending 0. if i change to `var result bson.M` it works but i don't think that is the correct way.

Comment: If it works with `bson.M`, that means that the query is correct, but when using struct, the mapping is incorrect. Please post your full code, not just the query. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: Also see edited answer about using a slice result (with `One()` it can't be a slice). Note that this example works for me, so you must provide your full code if it doesn't work for you in order to get help.

Comment: Also made an edit: if you change the query only, you must use lowercased `"value"`, or leave it as-is and provide a struct tag like `bson:"count"`.

Comment: Yes i changed .One to .All and yea soon as i changed it to lowercase value it all started working! thank you